# Application of abstract algebra for computer science/software engineering

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, applications, motivation

What are some cool applications of abstract algebra for computer science/software engineering?

A friend of mine has been invited to my university (most of the students are soon to be software engineers/CS) to give a short seminar on abstract algebra and he wanted to know how he could motivate students to learn and get interested in the subject.

Comment: Well, I was looking for any (if there exists) examples of how ring/field theory could help develop software in some area?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm